# Determine name to use with CreateFileMapping to detect if process is running

Tags: c++, windows

I use the following C/C++ code to detect whether my application is running:

```
bool ProcessIsRunning(void)
{
    // Checks to see whether the process is still running...
    bool bRunning = false;
    HANDLE hMapping = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 32, "NAME");
    if (hMapping)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
            bRunning = true;    // Still running...

        CloseHandle(hMapping);
    }

    return bRunning;
}
```

In the example above, I set NAME to "ImageProcessor" for our application ImageProcessor.exe and it works reliably. But when I try and detect other processes using the same technique, such as our 3rd party remote support tool TeamViewer.exe, it fails. I've tried "TeamViewer" and "TeamViewer.exe". Each time GetLastError just returns 0. Is there any way to find what "lpName" (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) should be for a 3rd party EXE? Possibly load the EXE into a binary editor or use Task manager?

I realise there are other techniques (such as CreateToolHelp32SnapShot) to find out if a process is working. This question is specific to CreateFileMapping and whether it can be used more generally for this purpose.

Comment: @user3670482: On the CreateFileMapping line (scroll to the right) I set "NAME" as "ImageProcessor". This works. Setting "NAME" as "TeamViewer" does not work.

Comment: @eryksun: OK, thanks...how do you go about finding out the name of the Section object for a 3rd party process? In Task Manager my application appears as "ImageProcessor.exe" and the remote support application appears as "TeamViewer.exe".

Comment: @user3670482: TeamViewer.exe appears in Task Manager and the process "TeamViewer.exe" can be found in the current list of processes using CreateToolHelp32SnapShot.

Comment: @eryksun: Aah, yes I understand now. Just checked my application startup code and we do create a file-mapping object named "ImageProcessor". We use this to prevent the customer accidentally running multiple instances of the application. I've inherited this code and had spotted that in passing months ago...but forgotten about it. TeamViewer.exe is probably not creating a file-mapping object (or at least not one I know the name of). So this technique is not suitable generally. Please answer with that detail and I'll accept the answer. Thanks!